# Administrative access to user's file via OneDrive for business API

Tags: onedrive

I'm developing a web application that access to OneDrive for Business via REST API.
My users have a hard time to configure user's refresh token to system,  because there are many users.

So, I'd like to access to all user's file with one administorator token.
However, it seems that OneDrive API does not have such a function.
What should I do?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 4):

Though there is no such feature to directly enable a button and access all users files. But yes there is a way. 
I too had the same issue and contacted Microsoft support.

They suggested me to add a user(let's have him the admin user) as secondary administrator to all the other users MySites. There are two ways

1) Before creating one drive accounts. 
-> If the users still not created their OneDrive accounts then the following setting helps to set admin as secondary admin to all users who will be creating their accounts in future.
-> GoTo SharePoint admin center-> and then goto user profiles.
->There you see my site settings. Click on setup my sites and and in the settings page go down to find my site secondary admin. Add the admin user in the field provided and click check box enable secondary administrator.

2) if user accounts already exits, you need to set secondary administrator to individual account spefically. 
->For this in user profiles click manage user profiles under people. And search for i. 
-> List of all the available users will be populated. Hover mouse to the user name to find the down arrow button click it to open the menu and click on manage site collection administrators. Now add the admin user in site collection administrator field and save.

These two methods help you to access all users drives from ui and api.

For the second procedure instead you can write a custom Microsoft SharePoint online script(which is indeed a power shell script) to set an user as secondary administrator.

Use the below powershell script to do this. save the below snippet to file.ps1 and run in [sharepoint online management shell](https://www.microsoft.com/en-in/download/details.aspx?id=35588).

```
Import-module msonline
Write-Host "Please input credential of administrator"
$cred = Get-Credential
Connect-MsolService -Credential $cred
Write-Host "Please enter tenant"
$tenant = Read-Host
$adminsite = "https://"+ $tenant +"-admin.sharepoint.com"
Connect-SPOService -Credential $cred -url $adminsite
Write-Host "Please specify the administrator user principal name which will be the admin member for all personal sites"
$admin = Read-Host
$usersLogin = Get-MsolUser |ForEach-Object {$_.UserPrincipalName}
foreach($user in $usersLogin)
 {
  $account,$domain = $user.Split("@",2)
  if ( $account.Contains("."))
   {
    $account= $account.Replace(".","_")
   }
  ElseIf ( $domain.Contains("."))
   {
    $domain= $domain.Replace(".","_")
   }
  $site = "https://" + $tenant + "-my.sharepoint.com/personal/"+ $account +"_" + $domain

  Set-SPOUser -Site $site -LoginName $admin -IsSiteCollectionAdmin $true
  Write-Host  $admin " has been added as an administrator for personal site " $site`n
 }
```